# Filling missing values using means and grouping by logics in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, missing-data

Have a dataframe in Python like that:

```
x1 x2 x3
a  1  1000
a  1  2390
a  1   ?
b  2  120
b  2  2000
```

So my goal is to filling in all the missing values in column x3. But if I'll use standard approach (pd.fillna(df.mean()) I wont get desirable results. I want to be able somehow do not simple mean() of the x3 column but only mean() for x3 for all the values which x1=a and x2=1. How can it be done in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform()` to fill missing values by group:

```
df['x3'] = df.groupby(["x1", "x2"])['x3'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using `join` and `fillna`

```
c = ['x1', 'x2']
df.fillna(df[c].join(df.groupby(c).mean(), on=c))

  x1  x2      x3
0  a   1  1000.0
1  a   1  2390.0
2  a   1  1695.0
3  b   2   120.0
4  b   2  2000.0
```